# bootstrap navbar-fixed-top larger than mobile phone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest bootstrap 2.3.2 in a wordpress site with the navbar being fixed on the top of the screen.

The menu items I am having in the navbar are around 10-12.

When I get on the iphone/android screens (landscape mostly) it shows me only the first 5 or 6 depending on the font size I've chosen to override. Is there a way to click the navbar icon and scroll the content area ( .nav-collapse ) ?

Here is my navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="mynavbar" style="position:fixed;z-index:9999;">
    <?php
    // Fix menu overlap bug..
    if (is_admin_bar_showing())
        echo '<div style="min-height: 28px;"></div>';
    ?>            
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">                    
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="<?php echo icl_get_home_url() ?>"><?php lm_display_logo(); ?></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
                <ul class="nav">
[li > a items depending on wordpress menu, which are around 10-20 ]
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your overrides. When I look at this on Bootply (http://www.bootply.com/68166) it shows all of the menu items (not just 5)

Comment: My problem is on the iphone native screens 567x320 or 480x320 (I think for the second) mainly, and it continues on the rotated screen. The nav-collapse does not scroll, it stays fixed on the screen height when opened. What I am trying to do is having the navbar on top of my pages and as I scroll the phone pages it would open/close the menu.